# Adding get-Method to POJO causes JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

i have a POJO class, which is used for deserialization using Jackson. This class contains the default constructor and getter and setter methods for all class variables.
Because I need some advanced logic on the content of the POJO i added a method

```
public String getRootModuleName()
```

But now my unit tests fail during deserialization with the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No value present (through reference chain: com.POJO["rootModuleName"])
```

To me it looks like Jackson recognizes a get-Method and thus derives, that there must be a similar JSON property for deserialization.
When i annotate the method with **@JsonIgnore** the tests succeed.

Can someone confirm that Jackson identifies required properties by get-prefix on method names?
Is @JsonIgnore a good solution or should i decouple the business logic from POJO design?

Comment: Out-of-the-box, with Jackson, any getter will result in a property in JSON. To prevent that for a utility method, `@JsonIgnore` is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are completely right, JSON Jackson recognizes property getters by "get" prefix. So, in your case the possible solutions are to use `@JsonIgnore` just like you did, or rename your method to have different prefix such as "retrieve", "extract" and so forth. I'd say using `@JsonIgnore` is the best way to go. So, in short your solution is correct